# Why doesn't my code recognize any Entities when trying to read from Postgres?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, orm

[folder structure in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZpcn.png)

Ansatt means Employee, and Brukernavn means Username. Just fyi, in Norwegian.

I'm following a short tutorial my lecturer gave us on how to connect to a Postgres server. I've made a new Schema/table in Postgres and added a test field to see if my java code works. The simple method in the main class is supposed to print out the two fields from the database added from the sql script. However I get an error message when trying to fetch this test information from Postgres. There is something wrong with the way my code searches for and identifies the Entities. In my case Ansatt, but I can't figure out what.

main and method for printing id and brukernavn(username):

```java
package oblig3;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class KommunisereMedDatabaseEnklere {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Ansatt a = finnAnsattMedId(101);

        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public static Ansatt finnAnsattMedId(int id) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("AnsattPersistenceUnit");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        Ansatt a = null;

        try {
            a = em.find(Ansatt.class, id);
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
        return a;
    }


}
```

xml file, think problem must be here somewhere:

```xml
<?xml version ="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

    <persistence-unit name="AnsattPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>oblig3.Ansatt</class>
        <properties>
            <!--GenerelleJPA properties -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:postgresql://*******/*******" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="*******"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="*******"/>

            <!--EclipseLink properties -->
            <!--Sehttps://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging -->
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="WARNING"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Class used as @Entity in database:

```java
package oblig3;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table (name = "Ansatt", schema = "oblig3_jpa")
@NamedQuery (name = "hentAlleAnsatte", query = "SELECT a FROM Ansatt a")

public class Ansatt {
    @Id private int id; 
        private String brukernavn;

    public Ansatt() {
    }

    public Ansatt(int id, String brukernavn) {
        this.id = id;
        this.brukernavn = brukernavn;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setBrukernavnd(String brukernavn) {
        this.brukernavn = brukernavn;
    }

    public String getBrukernavn() {
        return brukernavn;
    }


}
```

The sql commands I used to create table and schema in postgres:

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS oblig3_jpa CASCADE;

CREATE SCHEMA oblig3_jpa;
SET search_path to oblig3_jpa;

CREATE TABLE Ansatt
(
   id       INT,
   brukernavn   VARCHAR(4),
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into Ansatt (id, brukernavn)
values (101, 'spsh')
```

The code is supposed to print something like this to the console:
[101, spsh]

I get:
[EL Warning]: metamodel: 2019-04-08 19:37:17.834--The collection of metamodel types is empty. Model classes may not have been found during entity search for Java SE and some Java EE container managed persistence units.  Please verify that your entity classes are referenced in persistence.xml using either  elements or a global false element
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Unknown Entity bean class: class oblig3.Ansatt, please verify that this class has been marked with the @Entity annotation.

at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:810)

at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:688)

at oblig3.KommunisereMedDatabaseEnklere.finnAnsattMedId(KommunisereMedDatabaseEnklere.java:22)

at oblig3.KommunisereMedDatabaseEnklere.main(KommunisereMedDatabaseEnklere.java:11)

Comment: What is the structure of your project?

Comment: Added snapshot of folder structure at the top of post. From eclipse, If this is what you meant?